# Why might a calendar event show on a different day than intended?

Tags: google-calendar

There is a calendar event that I'm being invited to attend.  It is a repeating event, every second week, starting on the 15th, inviting many people in an organization using Enterprise Google Apps / for biz.  When it arrives in my email, it is listed as starting on the 22nd of the month.  I have screenshots showing it on the 22nd on my computer and the 15th on others' computers.  Many other invitees have it come in to them on the 15th (correct date).

It is acting as though it has the wrong start-date — but only for me.

I can add more details if asked.  I think this may be a bug but I want to confirm, is there any natural way this could occur?

Comment: @pnuts Good thought.  Yes, confirmed we are all in the same timezone.  I can't guess why that would lead to a 1-wk difference

Comment: It is acting as though it has the wrong start-date, but only for me.  I have wondered if other people accepted a long time ago, and thus were grandfathered into the correct cycle.  Evidence against is that new people are are invited today have the correct date.